# Wait for pageload in new page

Tags: cypress, wait, pageload, page-load-time, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

After I clicks on the URL to order, the page is not response after clicks

I do normally and the step redirects to new URL for continue Order button on cypress it cannot be
Please help

Comment: Does the tab show a page loading? Maybe check the console for any errors or logging messages.

Comment: No any error, do manual the page is going next step but after I clicks on cypress and wait, page still freeze without action more